# IOException while writing to text file despite locking the block

Tags: c#, locking, ioexception, streamwriter, appendtext

I know the answer *must* be out there somewhere, I applied suggestions both from many other questions and from MSDN itself but I'm probably overlooking something here.

This is my method, I use it to dump output to file. lock object declaration attached for clarity.

```
private static Object fileLock = new Object();
private static void WriteToFile(string msg, bool WriteLine)
{
    lock (fileLock)
    {
        msg = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " - " + msg;

        FileInfo F = new FileInfo("dump.txt");
        using (StreamWriter writer = F.Exists ? F.AppendText() : F.CreateText()) //<--THIS LINE THROWS
        {
            if (WriteLine)
                writer.WriteLine(msg);
            else
                writer.Write(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Question is: Why does the `using` line above throws an `IOException` complaining another process is using the file the 2nd time I call the method ?

I'm calling it like this around my code:

```
Console.WriteLine(something)
#if(DEBUG)
    Extensions.WriteToFile(something,true);
#endif
```

Again, I'm **sure** this is a trivial issue and someone else asked something like this getting the right answer, but I'm unable to dig it up.

**UPDATE**

Refactoring out the `FileInfo` object and switching to `File.XXX` methods made the code work fine. I still wonder what the issue was, anyway the issue looks like solved.

Comment: That doesn't compile, as you are accessing an instance member (`fileLock`) from a static method. What does the declaration of the lock identifier actally look like?

Comment: Are you running 2 instances of your application?

Comment: @Guffa fileLock is static indeed, that line wasn't copypasted like the rest of the code. edited to fix.

Comment: @sixlettervariables only one instance running, happens during debug

Comment: My next question would be why don't you just hold open the file during logging? And what other, if any, methods may access `dump.txt`? Are you looking at it from outside?

Comment: @sixlettervariables turns out i *did* overlook something. why should i keep opening/closing the file ? ^^ gonna try shuffling some code around and see what happens, then get back to you. BTW, no one else is touching that file.

Comment: question updated since a bit of refactoring apparently solved the issue. many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Guffa: declaration has to be private static object fileLock = new object();

@alex: Your code works just fine on my machine although it's a bit too complicated for the task imo.

```
static void Write(string text, string file)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(file))// Creates or opens and appends
        {
            sw.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

Maybe some antivirus or indexer locks your dump file.

Comment: accepted since refactoring out the FileInfo object seems to have solved the issue (wondering why, but still). thanks.